# WordPress update messed special characters

Tags: updates, characters, fonts

I updated WordPress core to the latest version and the result was less than perfect. All special font characters got messed up (site language is Polish) and it happened inside the admin panel too.

I, unfortunately, did not make a backup copy and I am looking for the resolution that does not include manually fixing every single character. The site address is:

http://www.krakvet.pl/artykuly/

Answer (score -1):

You should probably check your `db_charset` inside `wp-config.php`
and compare it to the database/tables' charset. That's all I can say now since I don't know your server configuration.

Comment: And how is that going to help?